# Who is the radio informer in King Rat by Clavell?

Tags: james-clavell, king-rat-clavell

In *King Rat* by James Clavell, two radios in the camp are found by the Japanese. The radios were found only because of an informer. Who was the informer?

For some time I thought that it was Smedley-Taylor, but my friends have proven to me that this makes no sense.

Who was the informer?

Answer (score 1):

Drinkwater, the chaplain.  He was completely immoral and self-serving.  He was also smart enough to figure out who was involved with the wireless, being in such close quarters.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please could you [edit] to add some quotes or more detailed evidence from the book to confirm these claims?